# How to query input element of ng-content from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

Creating a component like below

```
<div class="test-search-field"
  [ngClass]="{'expanding': expanding}">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

The user of this component will add an `input` element while using this component.

```
<my-input-container>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</my-input-container>
```

From the component I want to get hold of this input element, but getting errors while querying using `@ContentChild`.

```
@ContentChild('input') inputElemRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.inputElemRef);
    }, 2000);
```

But this `inputElemRef` is always coming undefined.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: This is a bit of a strange approach. Why not make a directive that sits on your input element itsself?

Comment: Yeah you are right, but somehow I this existing code which i cannot change

Comment: If you would also put a directive on the input, then you can have that directive register itsself with a service that is injected on the level of the my-input-container element. For an example, dive into the code of angular and try to find out how the fromControlName attribute knows what formControlGroup it is in. Or, take a look at the answer of Thomasz ...

Comment: @Davy can you please the link from where i can see the `formControlName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Query by the directive class token.

my-input.directive.ts

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myInput]',
})
export class MyInputDirective  {}
```

my-input-container.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, AfterContentInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInputDirective } from './my-input.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input-container',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class MyInputContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(MyInputDirective, { read: ElementRef }) child: MyInputDirective;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.child);
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<my-input-container>
  <input myInput />
</my-input-container>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khx4fx)

2. Query by the template variable.

If you only care about the ElementRef, you can skip the custom directive entirely, and query by the template variable instead.

my-input-container.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, AfterContentInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input-container',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class MyInputContainerComponent {
  @ContentChild('myInput') child: ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.child);
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<my-input-container>
  <input #myInput />
</my-input-container>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qchxvg)

In general the first option is preferrable and its what the `@angular/material` does with their input component. They pair the container component (`mat-form-field`) with a directive applied to the native input element (`matInput`).

It is more flexible, because you can query either for the Directive, or for the ElementRef.

`@ContentChild(MyInputDirective) child: MyInputDirective;`

`@ContentChild(MyInputDirective, { read: ElementRef }) child: MyInputDirective;`

Comment: This is right. But it be nice if you can tell what is the use of `@ContentChild `? What type of queries it accepts

Comment: It queries for the transcluded content. I'll edit my post with more info. Give me a minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help. I was thinking that @ContentChild was replacement to query selector or what people say angular way . I agree that directive is more cleaner way

Answer (score 2):

I would have used the renderer to do that.

Somethin like this **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bl6tyj?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const el = this.renderder.selectRootElement('input');
  console.log(el);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this will work. But I would appreciate if you also tell me if the `@ContentChild` should work or not. Also what type of query we can use

Comment: Well I believe `@ContentChild` is only for directives (and elements).

Comment: If element should work then what mistake I'm making in my code?

Comment: Elements as in Angular elements, not HTML tags.

Comment: Ohh... Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I'm not sure, hence the `I believe`, but that's my understanding from the documentation, and I can't seem to find examples with HTML tags. So yeah, probably find another solution for that !

Comment: Yeah... I'm too searching! I thought that @ContentChild to be the replacement for query selector or related js functions

Comment: Well from what I understood, the only way of handling the HTML is to use the renderer, that's why I advised you that. But let's be honest, for very simple functions, you still can use the query selector without having much trouble. And if you decide to, you can even run it with `ngZone` to run your code outisde of Angular or to integrate it.