# How to pass data to child component with ng-content?

Tags: angular

I have a modal component, example code this;

```
<nz-modal
  [nzWidth]="width"
  [nzTitle]="title"
  [nzVisible]="id === currentModal"
  [nzClosable]="closable"
  [nzFooter]="null"
  [nzCentered]="true"
  (nzOnCancel)="hideModal()"
>
  <ng-container *nzModalContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
</nz-modal>
```

Using modal;

```
  <modal title="Create New Item" id="createNewItemModal">
    <createNewItem-modal></createNewItem-modal>
  </modal>
```

I want to pass data to "createNewItem-modal" component with ng-content. How can i do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754467/how-to-query-input-element-of-ng-content-from-parent-component might help?

Comment: this is not what i need but thank you anyway